# jQuery UI autocompletion isn't working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to use jQuery UI with autocomplete but it doesn't show any list or anything. As far as I know there is no need to declare neither `ul`s nor `li`s with jQuery UI.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="./jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="./jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
        <script src="./jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input id="pu_location" size="38"  type="text" />                               
        <input type="hidden" id="pu_locationID" />

        <script>
            Script is below.
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Script:

```
 <script>

$( document ).ready(function() {

        $("#pu_location").autocomplete({

            source: function(request, response) {

            $.getJSON("/test.php", { country_code: "USA",term:$('#pu_location').val()}, 
                      function(data) {
                        alert(data[0].id);
                        var array =[];
                        for(key in data){
                            if (data[key].label!=''){
                                array.push(data[key].label);
                                }
                            }
                            alert(array);
                            response(array);
                        });
            },
            delay: 100, 
            minLength: 3                        
            });
}); 
</script>
```

By the way, the `data` is perfect. The `alert`s show that everything is fine.

Edited:
It works with Chrome now but not with Firefox!

Comment: Could you format that code o bit, It would be more pleasent for the eye:)

Comment: I tried. I'm using a simple text editor.

Comment: @Beri Without `$(function() {` and with `function(request, response) {` as function outside of `$("#pu_location").autocomplete({` code will look much better, you know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First clue:
Remove:

```
$(function() {
```

You were trying to create selfexecuting js function here, but it's not necessary, because you are already in ready function-annonymus function.

Then put an log just before line

```
$("#pu_location").autocomplete({
```

just to be sure this code is being executed.

Second clue: you reveive data on response, then you create and fill array, and in the end you pass to response data, so what is the sense of this processing?

Comment: It's executed and the alerts show the right data. I just removed that and still, the retrieved content won't be displayed

Comment: Also tried with data variable and the created array with strings, no luck.

Comment: Array reason: i thought that the response couldnt handle the objects so i made an array with strings. Didn't work.

Comment: _Your code propably is never executed._ - Code is executed. `$(function() {` is useless here, but not erroneous.

Comment: Whell Arnold wrote: 'alerts show', so we assume there are executed. But I agree with Regent - remove this 2 lines, they are making your code blury.

Comment: Edited the code and tried Chrome and it works. Not sure why firefox is failing so bad.

Comment: Seems like Firefox doesn't like alerts. Thanks for the help